# Подсчитать количество слов в заданном тексте. Исходный текст, его длину и количество слов вывести на экран

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Код на TASM. Выдает кучу ошибок. Подскажите правильно ли я считаю слова в предложении (опираясь на пробелы) и как посчитать длину предложения?

```
.data
mas db  'podschitat kolichestvo slov v zadannom tekste''$'
size=$-mas
text    db  'Iskhodnaya stroka:  podschitat kolichestvo slov v zadannom tekste',13,13,\'Slov v stroke:  '

.code
start:
assume ds:data,cs:
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

lea di,mas
mov cx,size
mov al,' '
mov bx,0
cld

m1:
 repne scasb
 jcxz   m2
 inc    bx
 jmp    m1
m2:
 inc    bx

mov ah,9
mov dx,offset text
int 21h

add bx,30h 
mov ax,0200h 
mov dx,bx
int 21h

mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: *Выдает кучу ошибок* -- каких именно ошибок?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Код считает количество слов в тексте и выводит длину строки,количеств слов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/719125/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)