# Код считает количество слов в тексте и выводит длину строки,количеств слов

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Есть код на Tasm.Пишет что в строке 3 слова.Подскажите как вывести длину строки и почему посчитал только 3 слова?

```
data segment para public "data"
mas db  'podschitat kolichestvo slov v zadannom tekste''$'
text1   db  'Slov v stroke: $ '
text2   db  'Dlina stroki: $'
data ends

code segment para public "code"
start:
assume ds:data,cs:code
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
lea di,mas
mov si,0
l1 :
 cmp byte ptr [di],0
 je l2
 inc di
 inc si

 jmp l1

l2 :
lea di,mas
mov cx,si
mov al,' '
mov bx,0
cld

m1:
 repne scasb
 jcxz   m2
 inc    bx
 jmp    m1

m2:
inc bx
mov ah,9
mov dx,offset text1
int 21h
add bx,30h 
mov ax,0200h 
mov dx,bx
int 21h
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Comment: 1) где инициализация es? 2) зачем вы ищете байт со значением 0? (его в строке нет)

Comment: @PinkTux 1)зачем ее инициализировать?2)замечание логично,но тогда не понимаю как посчитать длину,что бы в последствии подсчитать слова?

Comment: Не "её", а регистр `es`. У вас же не tiny (если я правильно понял), следовательно, пара `es:di` указывает вовсе не туда, куда вам хочется :) А чтобы посчитать длину (в данном случае это смысла не имеет, она и так известна на этапе ассемблирования) выберите критерий. Например, ищите символ `$` вместо нулевого байта.

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
P8086 
MODEL TINY

DATASEG
   test_string db '11  222   3333 ', 0

CODESEG 

   STARTUPCODE

   mov di, offset test_string
   push di

   mov cx, -1
   xor ax, ax
   cld
   repne scasb
   not cx
   dec cx ; здесь в CX получаем длину строки

   pop si
   xor bx, bx

skip_spaces:
   lodsb 
   or al, al
   jz finish
   cmp al, ' '
   jle skip_spaces
   inc bx

skip_word:
   or al, al
   jz finish
   cmp al, ' '
   jle skip_spaces
   lodsb
   jmp short skip_word

finish:
   ; а здесь в BX - количество строк
   ret
END
```